# Why showing Azure FTP server reset error?

Tags: azure, server, ftp, azure-web-app-service

[image]

I was trying to connect my azure FTP endpoint, it was showing some errors. I have enabled FTP services and disabled my window defender, still showing this error.

Comment: What about the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

- Verify that the user of FTP has the necessary permissions to access the Azure Web App.
- If you are not sure about the current credentials , change the FTP credentials in the User Scope section in Azure Portal

[image]

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/development-website/cannot-visit-ftp-sites) , When we try to access the `FTP` by using MS Internet Explorer , we get this error message

> Windows cannot access this folder. Make sure you typed the file name correctly, and that you have permission to access to the folder.

- Instead of File Explorer try to use FileZilla or WinSCP

**Taken references from:**

[using File Explorer or Internet Explorer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-access-ftp-using-file-explorer-or/c7efea72-9e8a-4ac2-82a5-d598dd3e1342)

[FTP-Access-through-Windows-Explorer](https://helpdesk.egnyte.com/hc/en-us/articles/201637914-FTP-Access-through-Windows-Explorer)

[Deploy content using FTP/S - Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?tabs=portal)